# How can I get a video iframe to appear underneath a modal pop-up in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, iframe, modal-dialog

A client's site has a youtube video iframe and a modal pop-up window on the same page.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx"></iframe>
```

*(I have excluded irrelevant data such as width, height and frameborder specs).*

All works well in every browser except Internet Explorer; here the **iframe appears on top of the modal window** when it is opened.

How do I stop this behaviour and **force the iframe to appear under the modal** like the rest of the page content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following needs to be included in the URL of the youtube video:

**?rel=0&wmode=transparent**

In context:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent"></iframe>
```